# Consumers unable to connect to eventhub i.e. Kafka using oauth2.0 authentication mechanism

Tags: java, apache-kafka, oauth, spring-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am trying to authenticate to azure eventhub i.e. Kafka using oauth2. I am using spring-Kafka for the consumer code and setting my values consumer config using Apache Kafka.
Consumer Code :

```
  @KafkaListener(
      topics = "${events.user.topicZR}", concurrency = "${events.user.concurrency}",
      containerFactory = "kafkaUserListenerContainerFactoryZr")
  public void processEventZr(ConsumerRecord<String, String> records,
                             Acknowledgment acknowledgment)  {
    consumeCoreEvent(records, acknowledgment);
  }
```

Consumer Config code :

```
@Bean(name = "kafkaUserListenerContainerFactoryZr")
  public KafkaListenerContainerFactory kafkaUserListenerContainerFactoryZr() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
        new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(userConsumerFactory(true));
    factory.setAutoStartup(true);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setSyncCommits(false);
    factory.getContainerProperties().setAckMode(ContainerProperties.AckMode.MANUAL_IMMEDIATE);
    factory.setErrorHandler(new SeekToCurrentErrorHandler((record, exception) -> {
    }, new FixedBackOff(retryInterval, retryMaxAttempts)));
    return factory;
  }

public ConsumerFactory<String, String> userConsumerFactory(boolean zoneRedundant) {
    String connectionStringUser;
    String bootStrapServer;
    if (zoneRedundant) {
      bootStrapServer = eventStreamingProperties.getEventhubUsersEventBootstrapServersZr();
    } else {
      bootStrapServer = eventStreamingProperties.getEventhubUsersEventBootstrapServers();
    }
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG,
        bootStrapServer);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,
        StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG,
        "org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "latest");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, 100);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, eventStreamingProperties
        .getEventhubUsersEventGroupName());

      props.put(
          CommonClientConfigs.SECURITY_PROTOCOL_CONFIG,
          KafkaProperties.SASL_SSL);
  
        props.put(KafkaProperties.SASL_MECHANISM, KafkaProperties.SASL_MECHANISM_VALUE);

        props.put(KafkaProperties.SASL_JAAS_CONFIG,
            String.format(KafkaProperties.KAFKA_OAUTH_MESSAGE,
                KafkaProperties.OAUTH_CLIENT_ID, spnClientId,
                KafkaProperties.OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET, spnClientPassword));

        props.put(KafkaProperties.SASL_LOGIN_CALLBACK, KafkaProperties.CUSTOM_CONFIG_AUTH_HANDLER);
        props.put(KafkaProperties.OAUTH_URL, spnAuthUrl);
        props.put(KafkaProperties.SSL_ENABLED_PROTOCOLS, "TLSv1.2");

    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
  }

CUSTOM_CONFIG_AUTH_HANDLER = I am using apache kafka 3.1.0 org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.secured.OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler

KAFKA_OAUTH_MESSAGE = org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule required %s=\"%s\" %s=\"%s\";
```

I am able to fetch the token from the IDP i.e. azure but when the consumers are connecting to the eventhub I am getting this error :

```
2022-07-28 10:41:03,321 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
2022-07-28 10:41:03,388 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2022-07-28 10:41:03,389 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2022-07-28 10:41:03,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2022-07-28 10:41:03,452 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerSaslClient: Setting SASL/OAUTHBEARER client state to RECEIVE_SERVER_FIRST_MESSAGE
2022-07-28 10:41:03,453 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to INTERMEDIATE
2022-07-28 10:41:03,487 DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | user] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Sending Heartbeat request with generation 25 and member id evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn.servicebus.windows.net:c:user:I:consumer-user-3-886a344f745945c3a83b05bc86386991 to coordinator evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2022-07-28 10:41:03,487 DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | user] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Sending HEARTBEAT request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=HEARTBEAT, apiVersion=1, clientId=consumer-user-3, correlationId=99) and timeout 30000 to node 2147483647: HeartbeatRequestData(groupId='user', generationId=25, memberId='evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn.servicebus.windows.net:c:user:I:consumer-user-3-886a344f745945c3a83b05bc86386991', groupInstanceId=null)
2022-07-28 10:41:03,517 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-2, groupId=user] Unexpected error from evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net/10.79.43.40; closing connection
java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.read(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:137)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.<init>(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.SaslAuthenticateResponse.parse(SaslAuthenticateResponse.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:729)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveKafkaResponse(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:508)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1339)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Trace Logs

```
2022-07-28 11:57:48,545 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer: [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net/10.79.43.40:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@f612459, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake NEED_UNWRAP channelId -1, handshakeResult Status = OK HandshakeStatus = FINISHED
bytesConsumed = 45 bytesProduced = 0, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 45
2022-07-28 11:57:48,545 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer: [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net/10.79.43.40:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@f612459, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSL handshake completed successfully with peerHost 'evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net' peerPort 9093 peerPrincipal 'CN=servicebus.windows.net, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, ST=WA, C=US' cipherSuite 'TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384'
2022-07-28 11:57:48,545 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.SslTransportLayer: [SslTransportLayer channelId=-1 key=channel=java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net/10.79.43.40:9093], selector=sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl@f612459, interestOps=8, readyOps=0] SSLHandshake FINISHED channelId -1, appReadBuffer pos 0, netReadBuffer pos 0, netWriteBuffer pos 45 
2022-07-28 11:57:48,546 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_APIVERSIONS_RESPONSE
2022-07-28 11:57:48,546 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Found least loaded connecting node evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,610 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to SEND_HANDSHAKE_REQUEST
2022-07-28 11:57:48,610 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to RECEIVE_HANDSHAKE_RESPONSE
2022-07-28 11:57:48,611 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Found least loaded connecting node evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,661 TRACE [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | cache] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Heartbeat: [Heartbeat groupID=cache] Sending heartbeat request with 3000ms remaining on timer
2022-07-28 11:57:48,661 DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | cache] org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-cache-1, groupId=cache] Sending Heartbeat request with generation 120 and member id consumer-cache-1-1067d4da-3618-4a05-90ef-4bd0e2aaaf67 to coordinator localhost:9092 (id: 2147482646 rack: null)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,661 DEBUG [kafka-coordinator-heartbeat-thread | cache] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-cache-1, groupId=cache] Sending HEARTBEAT request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=HEARTBEAT, apiVersion=4, clientId=consumer-cache-1, correlationId=12) and timeout 30000 to node 2147482646: HeartbeatRequestData(groupId='cache', generationId=120, memberId='consumer-cache-1-1067d4da-3618-4a05-90ef-4bd0e2aaaf67', groupInstanceId=null)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,675 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to INITIAL
2022-07-28 11:57:48,675 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.internals.OAuthBearerSaslClient: Setting SASL/OAUTHBEARER client state to RECEIVE_SERVER_FIRST_MESSAGE
2022-07-28 11:57:48,675 DEBUG [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Set SASL client state to INTERMEDIATE
2022-07-28 11:57:48,675 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Found least loaded connecting node evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net:9093 (id: -1 rack: null)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,740 WARN  [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] Unexpected error from evh-use2-dsoi-iam-authn2.servicebus.windows.net/10.79.43.40; closing connection
java.lang.RuntimeException: non-nullable field authBytes was serialized as null
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.read(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:137)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.message.SaslAuthenticateResponseData.<init>(SaslAuthenticateResponseData.java:86)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.SaslAuthenticateResponse.parse(SaslAuthenticateResponse.java:76)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:187)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.requests.AbstractResponse.parseResponse(AbstractResponse.java:109)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.parseResponse(NetworkClient.java:729)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveKafkaResponse(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:576)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.receiveToken(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:508)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.authenticator.SaslClientAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslClientAuthenticator.java:302)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.prepare(KafkaChannel.java:181)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys(Selector.java:543)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:481)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:560)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:265)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:236)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.poll(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:227)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerNetworkClient.awaitMetadataUpdate(ConsumerNetworkClient.java:164)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureCoordinatorReady(AbstractCoordinator.java:258)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:483)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.updateAssignmentMetadataIfNeeded(KafkaConsumer.java:1262)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1231)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1211)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollConsumer(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1521)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.doPoll(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1511)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.pollAndInvoke(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1339)
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:1251)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
2022-07-28 11:57:48,740 TRACE [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#1-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.common.metrics.internals.IntGaugeSuite: [Consumer clientId=consumer-user-3, groupId=user] sslCiphers: Removed a reference to CipherInformation(cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, protocol=TLSv1.2).  0 reference(s) remaining
```

CustomAuthenticationHandlerClass

```
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialFactory;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ClientCredentialParameters;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.ConfidentialClientApplication;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IAuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.IClientCredential;
import com.pointclickcare.sop.iamauthn.config.KafkaProperties;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.AuthenticateCallbackHandler;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerToken;
import org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerTokenCallback;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.security.auth.callback.Callback;
import javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException;
import javax.security.auth.login.AppConfigurationEntry;

@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthenticateCallbackHandler implements AuthenticateCallbackHandler {

  private static final String HTTPS = "https";
  private static final String URL_PROTOCOL_DELIMITER = "://";
  private static final String DEFAULT_ENDPOINT = "/.default";
  private ConfidentialClientApplication aadClient;
  private ClientCredentialParameters aadParameters;
  private String appId;
  private String appSecret;
  private String authUrl;

  @Override
  public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, String mechanism,
                        List<AppConfigurationEntry> jaasConfigEntries) {

    String bootstrapServer =
        (String) ((List) configs.get(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG)).get(0);
    URI uri = URI.create(HTTPS + URL_PROTOCOL_DELIMITER + bootstrapServer);

    String sbUri = uri.getScheme() + URL_PROTOCOL_DELIMITER + uri.getHost();

    // based on Azure documentation: The scope to request for a client credential flow is the name
    // of the resource followed by /.default
    this.aadParameters =
        ClientCredentialParameters.builder(Collections.singleton(sbUri + DEFAULT_ENDPOINT)).build();

    Map<String, ?> options = jaasConfigEntries.get(0).getOptions();
    this.appId = (String) options.get(KafkaProperties.CUSTOM_CONFIG_APP_ID);
    this.appSecret = (String) options
        .get(KafkaProperties.CUSTOM_CONFIG_APP_SECRET);
    this.authUrl = (String) options
        .get(KafkaProperties.CUSTOM_CONFIG_AUTHORITY_URL);
  }

  /**
   * Empty method not implementing it, since it is not implemented in other library implementation
   * as well.
   */
  @Override
  public void close() {
    // Do nothing
  }

  @Override
  public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException, UnsupportedCallbackException {
    for (Callback callback : callbacks) {
      if (callback instanceof OAuthBearerTokenCallback) {
        try {
          // get token from Azure
          OAuthBearerToken token = getOAuthBearerToken();
          OAuthBearerTokenCallback oauthCallback = (OAuthBearerTokenCallback) callback;
          // let kafka oauth callback to handle the token
          oauthCallback.token(token);
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException exp) {
          log.error("error when get oauth bearer token during the "
              + "eventhub oauth authentication", exp);
          // Restore interrupted state...
          Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
          throw new IOException(
              "error when get oauth bearer token in custom authenticate callback handler", exp);
        }
      } else {
        throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callback);
      }
    }
  }

  OAuthBearerToken getOAuthBearerToken()
      throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException, TimeoutException {
    if (this.aadClient == null) {
      IClientCredential credential = ClientCredentialFactory.createFromSecret(appSecret);
      this.aadClient =
          ConfidentialClientApplication.builder(appId, credential).authority(authUrl).build();
    }
    IAuthenticationResult authResult = this.aadClient.acquireToken(this.aadParameters).get();
    log.info("Token acquired while authentication eventhub using SPN");

    return new OAuthBearerTokenImpl(authResult.accessToken(), authResult.expiresOnDate());
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what `KafkaProperties` is, but some of your props keys should come from `SaslConfigs`. E.g. `KafkaProperties.SASL_MECHANISM` -> `SaslConfigs.SASL_MECHANISM`. Similarly, `SslConfigs` can be used.

Comment: KafkaProperties have public static felids like   public static final String SASL_SSL = "SASL_SSL"; public static final String SASL_MECHANISM = "sasl.mechanism";  public static final String SASL_JAAS_CONFIG = "sasl.jaas.config"; I can use SaslConfigs but I am uisn gmy custom class which has properties set like this

Comment: Sure, you're welcome to use the non-Kafka provided values, but ideally you use the constants provided from Kafka itself. In any case, can you get more debug information from the logs or your network response? TRACE level logs?

Comment: I have added the trace logs...I am unable to figure out the error...one thing with same setting If I am using customAuthnticationCallbackHandler instead of Kafka provided OAuthBearerLoginCallbackHandler it works fine, I want to not use my custom handler instead use kafka provided handler

Comment: And what does your custom class do differently? The error seems to indicate part of the buffer in [this method](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/requests/SaslAuthenticateResponse.java#L76) is null

Comment: Nothing it is calling Microsoft to get the token and giving that token back to the token handler method...this class is also doing the same calling the id provider URL to get the token...I see the token being received when I debug the

Comment: Can you share your code or a diff that compares to built in class?

Comment: I have added the custom authentication class.....

Comment: @NikhilDhirmalani - Were you able to solve it with custom things? I am also facing this issue from 2 weeks and dont have any solution yet. Do you've one ?

Comment: I am done...I was able to connect